# How can I execute `run` or `continue` in gdb, based on if it's attached to a running process?

Tags: gdb

i have a gdb command file with the snippet below, which sets up some things (like handlers, watchpoints, and catchpoints), then `run`s my program

however, if i connect to a gdbserver running my program, i want to use `continue` instead of `run`.  right now i use `sed` to search and replace the command to a new file, but i would prefer to use an environment variable or detect if the program is already running.

how can i do something like `if getenv("GDBSERVER")` or `run-or-continue`?